# Valet-plus : how to install mcrypt with php7.2 or php7.1

Tags: magento2, valet

**Pre-Condition**

1. Magento 2.2.6
2. Mac Os
3. Php7.1 or Php7.2

> main.CRITICAL: Warning: Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_BLOWFISH -
>   assumed 'MCRYPT_BLOWFISH' (this will throw an Error in a future
>   version of PHP) in
>   /Users/Anant/Desktop/Anant/Projects/cheapsheds/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php
>   on line 397 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Warning: Use
>   of undefined constant MCRYPT_BLOWFISH - assumed 'MCRYPT_BLOWFISH'
>   (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in
>   /Users/Anant/Desktop/Anant/Projects/cheapsheds/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php
>   on line 397 at
>   /Users/Anant/Desktop/Anant/Projects/cheapsheds/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61)"}
>   []

This is coming due to missing mcrypt module in php so, Can you please know me how i installed it using valet plus

Answer (score 1):

To install mcrypt on Valet Plus, run in Terminal:

```
brew install mcrypt
pecl install mcrypt
```

Check it has installed with:

```
php -m | grep mcrypt
```